# How to clone multiple git repos into the same workspace folder in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build-automation

> **Jenkins - v2.148**
>
> **Multiple SCMs plugin - v0.6**

There are multiple microservices in my project, In VSTS each falls under different git repository URLs. I'm trying to configure each of these microservice repos in jenkins.

Using Multiple SCMs plugin, I was able to add each repository using **Add Repository** option but whenever I initiate the build job, each repositories are being cloned into the same workspace folder. When the next repository in the queue is cloned, previously cloned code is removed. At the end, only the last repository source remains in the workspace folder.

**Check out to sub-directory** option didn't work, as this option is not available for each repository so that I could have configured each repo to clone into respective sub folders under the work space.

[image]

Is there a way to clone all the repos configured in Jenkins into separate folders into the workspace folder during a build job?

Comment: what do you mean - "Check out to sub-directory option didn't work"? attach a screen to show us its unavailable and why. I have a couple of multiscm projects and everything works

Comment: @hopetds As you can see in the screen shot, there is no place to specify sub-directory for each repository. Advanced option doesn't have that feature either.

Comment: "Additional behaviours" >> Add >> "Checkout to a sub-directory". Repeat this steps for every repository you have.

Comment: @JoaoVitorino This option is not repeatable for each repo. All I can do with this is to specif a directory under root folder(workspace) where the repos to be cloned. I'm using `Multiple SCMs plugin v0.6`

Comment: @Kurubaran did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @VinShahrdar unfortunately no, I ended up creating separate jobs for each repo.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using

[image: Add repository button]

you should use Add SCM and specify your git repository there. This way you will be able to set Additional Behaviours -> Add -> Checkout to a sub-directory for the new SCM. You can add as much SCMs as you need, each one with the option to be checked out to a sub-dir.

[image: Add SCM]

Comment: This is exactly what I need but the Jenkins I've inherited is too old.